# lazy loading on uicollectionview using dispatch_sync

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, lazy-loading, grand-central-dispatch

I want to load too many image after image processing each image.
but when i scroll up and down, lazy loading..
it's my code following.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
UICollectionViewCell *cell;
cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"FaceImageCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
UIImageView *fImageView = (UIImageView*)[cell viewWithTag:1];
[faceImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ic_loading"]];
NSLog(@"Loaded Image row : %d", indexPath.row);

ALAsset *asset;
    asset = [_imageList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    dispatch_async(all_f_d_queue, ^{
        ALAssetRepresentation *representation = [asset defaultRepresentation];
        NSString *filename = [representation filename];
        NSLog(@"%@", filename);
        UIImage *image, *fullImage;
        if ((fullImage = [_fullImageCache objectForKey:filename]) == nil) {
            image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[asset thumbnail]
                                             scale:[representation scale]
                                       orientation:(UIImageOrientation)[representation orientation]];
            vector<cv::Rect> f = [ImageUtils findFeature:image minsize:MIN_FACE_SIZE
                                                 withCascade:face_cascade];

            Mat imageMat = [ImageUtils cvMatFromUIImage:image];
            fullImage = [ImageUtils UIImageFromCVMat:imageMat];
            [_fullImageCache setObject:fullImage forKey:filename];
        }
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [fImageView setImage:fullImage];
            [cell setNeedsDisplay];
        });
    });
return cell;
}
```

Due to the many queue, it occured lazy loading.
I want to stop or cancel dispatch queue when loading cell is invisible.
How should I do for detecting cell to be invisible and for stopping dispatch queue?? 
Let me know please.
I could use asynctask in android. but I don't know how to implement that in iOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use NSOperation and NSOperationQueue.
It's pretty much the same as dispatchlib but is Object Oriented.
You can wrap the work on on NSOperation and then add that to an NSOperationQueue.
And then you can cancel an NSOperation whenever you want.
Probably have to read Apple documentations for better explanations of these two classes.

Comment: Thank you. one more thing, How can I detect for cell to be invisible?

Comment: there's a UICollectionViewDelegate method
– collectionView:didEndDisplayingCell:forItemAtIndexPath:
But, if I'd have to do that, I'd rather just cancel an operation for a cell if there's one before starting a new one on collectionView: cellForItem...

Comment: Hey, you know what, there's a wwdc 2012 video that tackles lazy loading on a tableView. I found this very helpful:
Building Concurrent User Interfaces on iOS
https://daw.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/DSAuthWeb.woa/wa/login?path=%2F%2Fvideos%2Fwwdc%2F2012%2Findex.php%3Fid%3D211&appIdKey=891bd3417a7776362562d2197f89480a8547b108fd934911bcbea0110d07f757

Answer (score 1):

Take a look on [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/19788/how-to-use-nsoperations-and-nsoperationqueues). It shows how you can download data asynchronously using NSOperationQueue and cancel this queue if user did scroll and this cell is not visible anymore.

Comment: Did you mean queue instead of queen? :)